# What is the formula for the Smart Body Mass Index?

Tags: body-weight, body-mass-index-bmi

The formula for the standard body mass index is mass divided by the square of height, where mass is in kilograms and height is in metres. It has been criticised in that its variation with height may not be optimal, and also because it takes no account of age or sex.

Various alternatives have been suggested. These include the Smart BMI, which is advertised [here](http://www.smartbmicalculator.com/). What formula does it use?

Comment: "Christian Bachmann is a biologist, medical journalist and webmaster" and this comes closest to revealing his formula without recreating it? http://www.gesundheit.ch/test/bmi-age.html (checking it reveals incompleteness)

Comment: You can find the authors and researchers contact details on the linked website. I would recommend sending him a nice email stating you are very interested in this and asking whether he has published the formula to calculate the SBMI in any venue.

Comment: Smart body mass index is brain mass divided by square of height ;-)